# Obtain value from select menu and perform operations on that in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create a `javascript` function for the following:

```
<td>
   <h4 class="subject-name">Construction Management</h4>
</td>
<td>
   <select id="sub9Score">
      <option selected value="Select Grade">Grade</option>
      <option value="10">S</option>
      <option value="9">A</option>
      <option value="8">B</option>
      <option value="7">C</option>
      <option value="6">D</option>
      <option value="5">E</option>
      <option value="0">F</option>
   </select>
</td>
```

Here, I want to get a selected value by user and assign the letter a value(number). Then I want to use that value for calculation and display that in an alert box. Please give me a code to assign a numerical value to user selected option. Use only `javascript`. No `jquery`

Can anyone find an error in my code here:

```
function calculator(){
        var sub1score = document.getElementById('sub1Score');
        var sub1 = sub1score.options[sub1score.selectedIndex].value;
        var sub2score = document.getElementById('sub2Score');
        var sub2 = sub2score.options[sub2score.selectedIndex].value;
        var sub3score = document.getElementById('sub3Score');
        var sub3 = sub3score.options[sub3score.selectedIndex].value;
        var sub4score = document.getElementById('sub4Score');
        var sub4 = sub4score.options[sub4score.selectedIndex].value;
        var sub5score = document.getElementById('sub5Score');
        var sub5 = sub5score.options[sub5score.selectedIndex].value;
        var sub6score = document.getElementById('sub6Score');
        var sub6 = sub6score.options[sub6score.selectedIndex].value;
        var sub7score = document.getElementById('sub7Score');
        var sub7 = sub7score.options[sub7score.selectedIndex].value;
        var sub8score = document.getElementById('sub8Score');
        var sub8 = sub8score.options[sub8score.selectedIndex].value;
        var sub9score = document.getElementById('sub9Score');
        var sub9 = sub9score.options[sub9score.selectedIndex].value;
        var total = (sub1*4)+(sub2*4)+(sub3*4)+(sub4*3)+(sub5*4)+(sub6*1.5)+(sub7*1.5)+(sub8*1.5)+(sub9*4);
        var gpa = total/27.5;
        var final = gpa.tofixed(2);
        alert('Your CGPA is '+final+'');
        }
```

Updated my javascript function. But this isnt displaying alert box:

```
function calculator(){
        var sub1score = document.getElementById('sub1Score');
        var sub1 = sub1score.options[sub1score.selectedIndex].value;
        var a = parseInt("sub1");
        var sub2score = document.getElementById('sub2Score');
        var sub2 = sub2score.options[sub2score.selectedIndex].value;
        var b = parseInt("sub2");
        var sub3score = document.getElementById('sub3Score');
        var sub3 = sub3score.options[sub3score.selectedIndex].value;
        var c = parseInt("sub3");
        var sub4score = document.getElementById('sub4Score');
        var sub4 = sub4score.options[sub4score.selectedIndex].value;
        var d = parseInt("sub4");
        var sub5score = document.getElementById('sub5Score');
        var sub5 = sub5score.options[sub5score.selectedIndex].value;
        var e = parseInt("sub5");
        var sub6score = document.getElementById('sub6Score');
        var sub6 = sub6score.options[sub6score.selectedIndex].value;
        var f = parseInt("sub6");
        var sub7score = document.getElementById('sub7Score');
        var sub7 = sub7score.options[sub7score.selectedIndex].value;
        var g = parseInt("sub7");
        var sub8score = document.getElementById('sub8Score');
        var sub8 = sub8score.options[sub8score.selectedIndex].value;
        var h = parseInt("sub8");
        var sub9score = document.getElementById('sub9Score');
        var sub9 = sub9score.options[sub9score.selectedIndex].value;
        var i = parseInt("sub9");
        var total = (a*4)+(b*4)+(c*4)+(d*3)+(e*4)+(f*1.5)+(g*1.5)+(h*1.5)+(i*4);
        var gpa = (total/27.5);
        var final = gpa.toFixed(2);
        alert('Your CGPA is '+final+'');
        }
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_mI455BxLOWS3V0UFNaVnNEUlU/view?usp=sharing Link to my full codes

Comment: Hi here in the value you have character. I am not sure exactly what you want to achieve

Comment: Suppose option S is selected, I want to assign that 'S' option a value of 10. Then I want to use this 10 for mathematical calculation

Comment: I want to know how to assign a value to selected option and use it for mathematical calculations

Comment: what are subscores in  getElementById('sub1Score')?

Comment: id of 'select' elements

Comment: Actually they are grades. Suppose user selects, A grade, Its value is 9

Comment: Please check my answer. Over there i am doing calculations. You have to use parseInt to use selected value for mathematical calculation.

Comment: added parseInt, But it isnt working. Updated my post. Please check that

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_mI455BxLOWS3V0UFNaVnNEUlU/view?usp=sharing  Link to all my codes

Comment: [`.toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) has a capital "F". You used lowercase, so your Javascript code fails (with an error in the console telling you why) before it gets to the alert line. You should look at your developer console (F12) before posting.

Comment: Fixed that 'Fixed'. Now the alert box is displaying 'NaN' and no result.

Answer (score 2):

You have forgotten to use parseInt because of it. It is not performing proper operations. Please check my updated answer.

```js
 var selectElement = document.getElementById("sub9Score");
    function getSelectedVlue(){
      var selectValue = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].value;
      if(selectValue== "Select Grade") return;
alert("select value is: "+
 selectValue);
     alert("adding 1 and selected value with out parse int "+ (1 + selectValue));  alert("adding 1 and selected value with parse int "+ (1 + parseInt(selectValue)));
    }
```

```html
<td>
                                        <h4 class="subject-name">Construction Management</h4>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                      <input type="button" value="Get Selected Value" onclick="getSelectedVlue()"> <br/><br/>
                                        <select id="sub9Score">
                                            <option selected value="Select Grade">Grade</option>
                                             <option value="10">S</option>
      <option value="9">A</option>
      <option value="8">B</option>
      <option value="7">C</option>
      <option value="6">D</option>
      <option value="5">E</option>
      <option value="0">F</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
```

Comment: I have assigned numbers in value. Eg: <option value="10">S</option>

Comment: Please check my updated answer. You have to use parseInt function to convert string to int then you can perform calculations using it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want number then assign value to letters

```js
function getSelectedVlue(){
  var e = document.getElementById("sub9Score");
  alert("you have selected : " + (e.options[e.selectedIndex].value));
}
```

```html
<td>
                                    <h4 class="subject-name">Construction Management</h4>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                  <input type="button" value="Get Selected Value" onclick="getSelectedVlue()"> <br/><br/>
                                    <select id="sub9Score">
                                        <option selected value="NA">Grade</option>
                                        <option value="19">S</option>
                                        <option value="1">A</option>
                                        <option value="2">B</option>
                                        <option value="3">C</option>
                                        <option value="4">D</option>
                                        <option value="5">E</option>
                                        <option value="6">F</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
```

Comment: I have assigned numbers in value. Eg: <option value="10">S</option>

Answer (score 0):

Get the element using the ID you've already defined. Then define a handler for the [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event which does something with the `value` property.

```js
var sub9Score = document.getElementById('sub9Score');

sub9Score.onchange = function() {
  console.log(this.value)
};
```

```html
<select id="sub9Score">
  <option selected value="Select Grade">Grade</option>
  <option value="S">S</option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
  <option value="E">E</option>
  <option value="F">F</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I have assigned numbers in value. Eg: <option value="10">S</option>